# How do I use INNER JOIN and still query rows without reference

Tags: sql

I have the following sample tables...

**Table1**:

```
F1   F2     
 2   Chris  
 5   John   
 8   Smith
```

**Table2**:

```
F1   F2
 2   New
 5   Old
 8   New
 9   New
```

My tables might not make too much sense but they're only samples. Anyways... If I use this SQL statement...

```
SELECT 
    T2.*,T1.F2
FROM 
    Table2 T2
INNER JOIN 
    Table1 T1 ON T2.F1 = T1.F1
```

I should be able to get the rows shown below...

```
T2.F1  T2.F2  T1.F2
 2     New    Chris
 5     Old    John
 8     New    Smith
```

However, this is not what I want... I'd like to get the rows without the reference from doing the `INNER JOIN` too. If no reference is found, a null should be returned for that field, but still have the same # of rows returned like this...

```
T2.F1  T2.F2  T1.F2
 2     New    Chris
 5     Old    John
 8     New    Smith
 9     New    NULL
```

How do I do this? Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this using an `INNER JOIN` - you need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead :

```
SELECT 
    T2.*,T1.F2
FROM 
    Table2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Table1 T1 ON T2.F1 = T1.F1
```

Comment: This Sir worked like a charm :) Thanks a million. I've already achieved the desired output using 2 SQL statements. I looped through the rows returned by the 1st statement and query again using the 2nd statement for each row returned from the 1st. Which is more efficient? Using 2 SQL statements or using the LEFT OUTER JOIN clause? I bet it's using the clause that's more efficient, but since the server basically does the same thing as 2 SQL statements (or doesn't it?), I just want to be sure :)Thanks :)

Comment: **ONE** statement that does it all is much more efficient, **especially** if you *loop through the results* in a RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) fashion - SQL is a **set-based** language - try to avoid manual *looping* as much as possible!